# jQuery animate only change what is asked for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm running this function and it works, but it changes more than I want.

```
<div id="animate" style="background: #999999; width: 100%;"></div>

$('#animate').animate({width: '50%'}, 500, function() {});
```

Result when I look at it in firebug:

```
<div id="animate" style="background: rgb(153, 153, 153) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 50%;"></div>
```

I know that the background will look the same, but is there a way to tell it to ONLY change 100% to 50% and not touch the background?

Comment: I dont see color changing https://jsfiddle.net/stack26/o2gxgz9r/21409/. check the fiddle

Comment: In my firebug that turned out: `background: rgb(153, 153, 153) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 50%; height: 50px;`

Comment: have you tried to put the style in css and not do the css inline style?

Comment: And in chrome's console: `background: rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 50%; height: 50px;`

Comment: Are you just worring about the COMPUTED background-color changing from `#999999` to `rgb(153, 153, 153)` ?

Comment: #999999 == rgb(153). (bah, Louys got to that before me)

Comment: loool @Mox... We agree that question should be closed then.

Comment: Yes! I'm running a comparison that checks if anything has changed in the element. And after the jQuery animate my script (not listed here) gives me a message that the content has changed even if it hasn't. I moved the background out of there but the "old" and edited element still doesn't equals even if it animates from 100% to 100%. I guess that's another thread to post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is not a question. It is just a misunderstanding from OP about computed style of the browser.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No I totally understand that it's technically the same, but that is not my issue.

Comment: @SeaBass: What's the issue then?

Comment: @SeaBass .animate explicitly changes an element. I echo Louys: what's youre issue? Your comparative script must not be correct. Ask another question in regards to your script.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette See my post about comparing above. I'm basically running a if(1==1), but it doesn't turn out true. To simplify: I compare a div with width 100% with the same div after running jQuery animate width to 100% and the two don't equal. You might wonder why I want to do this, but I'm just curious why the animate changes other things.

Comment: Without the background and just the width it looks the exact same in firebug before and after, but still my script says they're different. Note that my script works on other elements. Thanks again guys. I'll start a new thread about that.

Comment: The `.animate()` changes what you tell it to change. The `background-color` was changed BY THE BROWSER... not by `.animate()`. **Now** you talk about comparing `width`. There is also a COMPUTED width. `100%` is the relative value you give before computing... It finally ends in pixels.

Comment: There is no "compiler" to JavaScript or jQuery... Like there is in many other languages... The browser handles that and does its own compliling. Where so many browser compatibility issues are originating from, by the way. That... I could post it as an answer, since it is your root question. But that isn't about "programming issue", that is about a wide programming basic concept understanding... You just missed your client-side browser JS introduction class, probably.

Comment: Well... I just can't find a duplicate question for that. Your question May be relevant to SO community. After all... It looks so basic, maybe no one asked before. So I upvote your question, retract the close vote and answer. Okay?